# How to find multivalued dependencies that not satisfy R?

Tags: database, dependencies, database-normalization, multivalue

I'm currently taking the course on DB and the theme is Relational Design Theory. Sub-theme is Multivalued dependencies and I'm completely lost in them :(

I have such a question:

```
R(A,B,C):
A | B | C
----------
1 | 2 | 3
1 | 3 | 2
1 | 2 | 2
3 | 2 | 1
3 | 2 | 3
```

Which of the following multivalued dependencies does this instance of R not satisfy?

```
1. AB ↠ C 
2. B ↠ C 
3. C ↠ A 
4. BC ↠ C
```

I know that:

```
A | B  | rest
----------
a | b1 | r1
a | b2 | r2
a | b1 | r2
a | b2 | r1
```

I'm making tables for those dependencies in those manner:

```
B ↠ C

B | C | A
----------
2 | 3 | 1
2 | 2 | 1
2 | 1 | 3
2 | 3 | 3
3 | 2 | 1
```

According to my assumptions:
`2 2 1` and `2 1 3` are at rule above, so there also should be `2 1 1` and `2 2 3` records.

So this one is not correct. Am I right?

And I don't have any idea how to build such table for `AB ↠ C`. It will be the same table?

```
A | B | C
----------
1 | 2 | 3
1 | 3 | 2
1 | 2 | 2
3 | 2 | 1
3 | 2 | 3
```

Is it something that called trivial dependency?

Comment: Can you tell me what is 1,2,3 value here ??

Answer (score 0):

Let me stretch my mind back to college days, from my Database Modeling Concepts class... Taking a quick refresher course via [some online PDFs](http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/stjohn/teaching/db/ullmanSlidesF00/slides5.pdf)...

I wrote and rewrote a paragraph here to try to concisely explain the multidetermines operator, but I can't explain it any more clearly than the PDF above. Roughly speaking, if `B ↠ C`, then for every `(B, C, A)` tuple that exists, you can swap out any `C` value in `(B, C) in R` and still find a tuple in `R`.

In the case of your last question, you're right. I don't remember the proper term, but since there are no other columns than `A, B, C`, then `AB ↠ C` is trivially satisfied in `R`. To build a table for it, I'd order by A first, then B. It would look something like

```
A | B | C
---------
1 | 2 | 2
1 | 2 | 3
1 | 3 | 2
3 | 2 | 1
3 | 2 | 3
```

`B ↠ C` is a much more interesting example.  Since the `(B, C, A)` tuples `(2, 3, 1)` and `(2, 1, 3)` both exist, the tuples `(2, 1, 1)` and `(2, 3, 3)` (obtained by swapping `C`) must both exist to satisfy `R`. Since `(2, 1, 1)` does not exist, it does not satisfy `R`. Writing out the tables like you did makes it quite easy to see.

If you see the examples in the PDF I linked earlier, it puts meaningful names to the columns, which may aid in your understanding. I hope this sets you on the right path!